# Comparison with reference list to convert to binary encoding

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a reference list like this

```
ref = ['August', 'July', 'June', 'May', 'April']
```

And some sample list

```
list1 = ['July', 'April']
list2 = ['August']
list3 = ['August', 'June', 'April']
list4 = ['April', 'June', 'May'] # Not sorted in decreasing order, as others
```

I want to compare element by element for each list with ref list, and if element is present change to 1 else 0

Hence when I run a function, my expected output is

```
compare(ref, list1) - [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
compare(ref, list2) - [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
compare(ref, list3) - [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

for list4, I need to first sort it into descending order and then compare

```
list4 = ['June', 'May', 'April']
compare(ref, list3) - [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Currently, my compare function looks like this

```
def compare(lst1, lst2):

    binary_list = [] #final list to return
    j = 0 #counter to keep check on lst2
    lst2_len = len(lst2) #length 

    for item in lst1: #main loop of ref list
        if j < lst2_len: #check counter is less than len of other list
            if item == lst2[j]:
                binary_list.append(1)
                j = j + 1
            else:
                binary_list.append(0)
        else:      # lst2 exhausted, append 0 to remaining months
            binary_list.append(0)

    return binary_list
```

Can I do better? I know that my reference list is always sorted. Hence

1. How can I sort the other list which contains month of year in descending order?
2. Once sorted, I need to convert it into binary encoding compared with reference list.

I am working on millions of records, and using `pandas` `apply` is taking a lot of time. Other list is present in a column.

Can I optimise it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'List2':[['July', 'April'], ['August'], ['August', 'June', 'April'], ['April', 'June', 'May']]})
>>df
  List2
0 [July, April]
1 [August]
2 [August, June, April]
3 [April, June, May]

df['List2'].apply(lambda x: compare(ref, x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since pandas is tagged, you can take advantage of [`series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) where sorting is not necessary:

```
def compare(r,l):
    s=pd.Series(r)
    return s.isin(l).astype(int).tolist()
```

---

```
print(compare(ref,list1))
print(compare(ref,list2))
print(compare(ref,list3))
print(compare(ref,list4))
```

---

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: yes this will work, but if I have same months, say for last 2 years, in that case each month will be twice. But thank you for this answer

Comment: @Hardikgupta i didnt get that, can you update the question with a bit more details as you said on the duplicates but different years. right now I am confused since the dataframe you posted after the edit has just month names as a list in a series?

Comment: yes, they are currently month names, however of last 12 only. Question is, If I extend this list to last 24, we will have each month two times (one from each year). It can happen August of 1 yr is present but not of last yr, in which case this solution will fail

Comment: right now this solution definitely solves my problem, but I am wondering if I have to take 2 yrs data, can it be accomodated

Comment: how do you avoid apply here? that is taking a lot of time

Comment: @Hardikgupta why not try with a list comprehension `df['new_col']=[pd.Series(ref).isin(i).view('i1').values for i in df.List2]`

Comment: what is i1 here?

Comment: list comprehension is equally expensive :(